# Javascript - Get a date from any kind of string

Tags: javascript, string, date

I would like to know if there is a way (I hope there is one, or I am in trouble :p), to find a date in any kind of string.

Here are some examples to make you understand what I am looking for :

```
var string1 = 'blabla-test-20140215.dat'
```

I would need to have access to '20140215'

```
var string2 = 'blabla_Test.20141212'
```

I would need to have access to '20141212'

Well, I would like to be able to find a date in a format yyyymmdd in a string, no matter the string.

Thank you if you have any clue, I haven't found anything on internet yet.

**EDIT :**

There can be other numbers in the string, but always less than 8.
for instance :

```
var string3 = 'blabla-2526-20141212'
```

The date I am looking for is always separated from other numbers. I can't have :

```
var string4 = 'blabla-252620141212'
```

I just want to find the numbers representing the date (in a format yyyymmdd, for instance in string3 I want 20141212, which refers to : 12/12/2014)

Comment: Take a look at moment.js

Comment: What if the string is "1234520141212"?

Comment: Any time you have exactly 8 numbers together, what about if you've got more than 8 together? Less than 8? Ignore those cases or try to parse each substring of 8?

Comment: Are the formats always ISO8601?

Comment: I have edited my question, thank for your interest. I will take a look at moment.js

Comment: Ask it out to dinner! ;)

Comment: @rsegal :) But would that work for **any kind** of string? It might make it think you think it's fat. Possibly a movie is more widely acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple enough to extract a sequence of eight numbers from a string with regex, just use something like the following:

```
var dateString = (/\d{8}/.exec(string) || [])[0];
```

This will find the first eight-character-long string of numbers in a given string. If no such sequence exists, it will be undefined. You can then use it to create a Date object if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I'm note sure, but if your string contains digits only for date, you can use RexEx ?

may be like this :

```
var regex = /[0-9]+/;
var string1 ="blabla-test-20140215.dat";
var found = regex.exec(string1); 
alert('Found: ' + found);
```

Comment: Of course (after your edit) this piece of code will not work with string3.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Regex for this.

```
re = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g //create a regex that matches: 4 digits followed by 2 digits followed by 2 digits
///// yyyy     mm       dd  
result = re.exec(string1) //execute the regex
// now, access the different capture groups according to their indexes
console.log(result[1]) // yyyy
console.log(result[2]) // mm
console.log(result[3]) // dd
```

Comment: Hooray! You should read more about Regular Expressions if you're working with strings, they're amazing. And how about an upvote? :)

Comment: Yes I have to improve my general knowledge :) Oups sorry for the upvote !

Answer (score 2):

This solution will check for valid dates (not just any 8 arbitrary numbers):

```
function hasDate(input) {
    var matches = input.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/),
        indexOf = function (elem, arr) {
            var len = arr.length, i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (arr[i] === elem) {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        },
        months31 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12],
        idx, isLeapYear,
        year, month, day;
    if (matches) {
        year = parseInt(matches[1]);
        month = parseInt(matches[2]);
        day = parseInt(matches[3]);

        //Check invalid dates from the start
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            return false;
        }

        idx = indexOf(month, months31);
        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0);        

        //Month has 31 days, we are good
        if (idx >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        //Feb - check for leap year
        else if (month === 2 && (day <= 28 || (isLeapYear && day <= 29))) {
            return true;
        }
        //All other months
        else if (month !== 2 && day <= 30) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //If we got this far, its a bad date
    return false;
}

//return true
hasDate('blabla_Test.20141212');
//return false
hasDate('blabla_Test.20140229');
//return true
hasDate('blah_20140228');
//return true
hasDate('blah_20000229');
```

Comment: Great work. I have 2 comments. One, you shouldn't define indexOf anymore, it's supported in [all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Two, It might be better if the function actually returns the date in an array (or undefined if not found) instead of true/false. Moreover, It would be smart to handle the case that there are 2 sequences of 8 digits, and only one of them correct. (In that case, the function should recall itself until it finds a valid date.)

Comment: indexOf was only defined to take into account IE8. As a Web Developer, I would like to stop supporting this myself, but realistically, most are still on XP with IE 8... And you can do whatever you want with the logic -- I was just trying to answer the OP question of to determine if there was a date in the string (Boolean).

Comment: "Most" applies for our application from what Google Analytics reports. I would like it to be otherwise too, trust me :)

Comment: @Patrick Then you should use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), so if indexOf is already defined by the browser it would use the native function.